# How to immobilize a mob in a script?

Tags: c++, azerothcore, world-of-warcraft

To fix the Gruul script, I need to immobilize the boss in an already existing event and remove that flag in another.
However, I can't find a way to prevent Gruul from chasing his target.
I tried comparing it to permanently snared bosses like Ragnaros and C'thun without finding a flag which fits my intentions.
Any hint, how to temporarily prevent movement is appreciated.

I am working on https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/src/server/scripts/Outland/GruulsLair/boss_gruul.cpp

I want to add code which immobilizes Gruul while casting "Ground Slam" until he casts "Shatter" to make it blizzlike.

In detail
https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/389227e4f7ea75292549a36d4f288cc2467d1078/src/server/scripts/Outland/GruulsLair/boss_gruul.cpp#L119
this event needs to immobilize him and this one https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/389227e4f7ea75292549a36d4f288cc2467d1078/src/server/scripts/Outland/GruulsLair/boss_gruul.cpp#L126
should make him move again.

I've been looking through the Wiki, trying various flags to no avail. Thankfully i got some replies on discord which suggested `UNIT_FLAG_PACIFIED` (which prevents attacks but does not immobilize from my tests) and `UNIT_FLAG_STUNNED` (which prevents the "Ground Slam" cast from being finished but does not prevent Gruuls movement either.

To achieve the above, i used this syntax, adding the 4 lines setting/removing flags:

```cpp
case EVENT_GROUND_SLAM:
  Talk(SAY_SLAM);
  me->CastSpell(me, SPELL_GROUND_SLAM, false);
  events.DelayEvents(8001);
  events.ScheduleEvent(EVENT_GROUND_SLAM, 60000);
  events.ScheduleEvent(EVENT_SHATTER, 8000);
  me->SetFlag(UNIT_FIELD_FLAGS, UNIT_FLAG_PACIFIED);
  me->SetFlag(UNIT_FIELD_FLAGS, UNIT_FLAG_STUNNED);
  break;
case EVENT_SHATTER:
  Talk(SAY_SHATTER);
  me->RemoveFlag(UNIT_FIELD_FLAGS, UNIT_FLAG_PACIFIED);
  me->RemoveFlag(UNIT_FIELD_FLAGS, UNIT_FLAG_STUNNED);
  me->CastSpell(me, SPELL_SHATTER, false);
  break;
```

Comment: please provide the link of the code you're trying to change, as well as the other working examples (github links should be also ok)

Comment: added code and links

Comment: `SetCombatMovement(false)` - no movement, 

`SetCombatMovement(true) - allow movement`

The above does not solve it either. It seems to work only out of combat.

Answer (score 0):

This code makes the boss (here: Gruul) stay in place.

`me->SetControlled(true, UNIT_STATE_ROOT);`

Setting the first argument to false removes the root.
Thanks to Yehonal on discord for pointing this out.